# iOS: Gloss Date decoding issue

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, swift3, gloss

I use Gloss for parsing `JSON`. I've got issues with parsing `Date` fields. My `JSON` input:

```
"PurchasedAt": 2016-08-02T17:23:12.000Z,
```

Struct:

```
let purchasedAt: Date?

init?(json: JSON) {

    self.purchasedAt = Decoder.decodeDate("PurchasedAt", dateFormatter: LTUtilities.getDateFormatter()) (json)

}


static func getDateFormatter() -> DateFormatter {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
        return dateFormatter
    }
```

Finally, I keep getting nil value for any `Date` field. Your help is very appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello friend , your problem is related to the format of your time stamp, check my previus answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466837/why-does-it-return-nil-when-i-unwrap-the-array-of-strings-in-localnotification/37467175#37467175, I hope this helps you, if not, then let me know, and I help you

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately changing the format didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Not sure if related to your issue, but I'd bet that "2016-08-02" means "yyyy-MM-dd" and not "yyyy-dd-MM".

Comment: It's true and and corrected, but still doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, solved this issue by myself with

```
"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS'Z'"
```

`DateFormatter` format string.